# HTML + Javascript - Combining Static URL with document.referrer

Tags: javascript, html

I currently use this code on my "thank you for commenting page" on my blog:

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href = document.referrer;" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'"> Click here</a>
```

When someone clicks on the anchor "click here", they are taken back to the page that they were on last. Since this "thank you for commenting page" is only accessible after they have landed on one of my posts and added a comment, there will always be a document referrer (wont ever be blank).

Since this was working nicely, I thought that I could add something like "We really appreciate your comment. If you want to help this blog, please consider sharing the article you have just read on Twitter" (I can include others later).

I want to anchor "Twitter" with the static share URL (http://twitter.com/?status=) with the document.referrer variable. I tried something like this without success:

http://twitter.com/?status=' + 'document.referrer;'">test

Another unsuccessful attempt:

```
<script>
document.write('<a href="http://twitter.com/?status=' + document.referrer + ">test</a>');
</script>
```

Basically I want the end result to look like this:

http://twitter.com/?status=http://www.myexampleblog.com/category/lastvisitedpost/

I have been fighting with this for a couple hours now but due to my limited coding knowledge, I am struggling. Please can someone help me? I know this could also probably be done with a function or perhaps done a better (or cleaner) way using php but I really just want to use an  with javascript if possible.

Thanks in advance :)

Jared

Comment: I think that this works, just doing a couple tests:

<script language="JavaScript">
document.write("<a href='http://twitter.com/?status=",document.referrer,"'>Go back</a>");
</script>

Comment: Hey! Yes it works, its strange how you can work things out quicker, just by outlining what you are trying to do and what has been tried. I just suddenly understood what needed to be done. On a positive note, I hope that this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
document.write('<a href="http://twitter.com/?status=' + document.referrer + '">test</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to test this at least localhost, not as regular files like say on your desktop. I've added an alert to help you out...

**1.html**

```
<a href="2.html">2.html</a>
```

**2.html**

```
<a href="javascript:alert('document.referrer = '+document.referrer);window.location.href = document.referrer;"> Click here</a>
```